# Bundler won't install

Tags: ubuntu, rvm, bundler

I'm in a strange situation, I install bundler in my RVM gemset, it sais it installed correctly, but when I try to run it asks me to to install bundler again: here is a transcript of my terminal interaction:

```
abc@li243-166:/srv/www/dinner/current$ bundle
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
abc@li243-166:/srv/www/dinner/current$ gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed
abc@li243-166:/srv/www/dinner/current$ bundle
ERROR: Gem bundler is not installed, run `gem install bundler` first.
abc@li243-166:/srv/www/dinner/current$
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll likely need to run an `rvm use ruby-x.y.z-pA` command to set up the specific ruby environment you're using, and especially gemset. Once that's done, it should all be good.

Comment: thanks, but not much worked besides re-installing the gem and gemsets...

Answer (score 0):

I've had to re-install the gem and gemsets